# Restoring previous state in Redux when going back in history with React-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, state

I have a React/Redux app that uses React-router. The app has a search area, which let's the users search for items.

There are ~200 items, so they are pre-loaded when the app starts.
The search just filters those items, without doing any further requests to the server.

When the user clicks on one of the items, the router goes to the details of that item.

Is there a best™ / common / generic way I can preserve the results and the scroll position and restore them if the user clicks on `Go back` while in the details view?

Answer (score 0):

You could use localStotage. Create subscribe function for store like this

```
store. subscribe (() => {
  // check here for your filter state for e.g.
  localStotage.setItem(...)
})
```

and then load from localStorage if needed on this page